# Quicksort with double* values

Tags: c, double, quicksort

I am given a programme in C which implements Quicksort on arrays with int values. I need to convert it into a programme which will implement Quicksort on arrays with double* values. I thought that I just need to change "int" declarations into "double*", but for some reason the programme no longer works when I test arrays with other values than integers.

Can someone please help? I really know almost nothing about programming in C and have no idea how to go on. Here is the "int" programme:

```
void quicksort(int a[], int n)
{
    if (n <= 1) return;
    int p = a[n/2];
    int b[n], c[n];
    int i, j = 0, k = 0;
    for (i=0; i < n; i++) {
        if (i == n/2) continue;
        if ( a[i] <= p) b[j++] = a[i];
        else            c[k++] = a[i];
    }
    quicksort(b,j);
    quicksort(c,k);
    for (i=0; i<j; i++) a[i] =b[i];
    a[j] = p;
    for (i= 0; i<k; i++) a[j+1+i] =c[i];
}


int main(void) {
    int i;
    /* das Array zum Sortieren */
    int test_array[] = { 5, 2, 7, 9, 6, 4, 3, 8, 1 };
    int N = sizeof(test_array)/sizeof(int);

    quicksort(test_array,  N);

    for(i = 0; i < N; i++)
        printf("%d ", test_array[i]);
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If not homework, just use `qsort()` from the stdlib.

Comment: And if it is homework, your quick sort algorithm is *way* more complicated than it needs to be. But I commend you for using a single array and length for the parameters. Most beginning implementations don't even do that right (yours is still off, but the effort was there at least). Fyi, you don't need `b[]` or `c[]` to do this at all.

Comment: @WhozCraig I'm not too concerned about complexity. The problem is I don't really understand conceptually what has to be done to make the programme work for double*.

Comment: Its not just a complexity thing. Its a comparison thing. But It would be enormously helpful if you posted the `double` version that is broken, because in your question and title you refer to changing `int` to `double*` (note, `*` as in pointer-to-double), yet in one place in your question you say "I thought that I just need to change "int" declarations into "double"..." So which is it? are you sorting `double` or `double*`, and if it is the latter, are you *sure* you want to do that?

Comment: @WhozCraig    it is "double*" indeed. That's what my homework problems tells me to do.

Comment: Do you really mean an array of pointers to `double`, or do you mean an array of `double`? There's quite a big difference (if only because there's more setup work involved in creating an array of pointers to `double`).

Answer (score 2):

When you replace the `int`s with `double` pointers, you need to change the comparisons - to compare the pointed to values, not the pointers themselves.

Comment: I know I must sound terribly ignorant, but I don't know what "pointers" and "the pointed" mean in this context.

Comment: I know I must sound terribly ignorant, but I don't know what "pointers" and "the pointed" mean in this context. Do I need to put some asterisks in?

Comment: @Balerion_the_black reread your question, and clarify it. Are you sorting an array of `double` or an array of `double*`. There is a *world* of difference.

Comment: @WhozCraig  . double* .

Comment: @WhozCraig  Yes...I don't really understand this difference.

Comment: @Balerion_the_black Almost certainly, the objective of the homework is to make sure you do understand the difference. Not understanding it is going to make further learning difficult. I suggest rereading your lecture notes, the current chapter in the course textbook etc. A quick web search led to [A TUTORIAL ON POINTERS AND ARRAYS IN C](http://pw1.netcom.com/~tjensen/ptr/pointers.htm) which may help. You probably only need the first couple of sections right now.

Comment: @Balerion_the_black if it is as you say, then this answer makes perfect sense. Sorting a `double[]` is one thing. Sorting a `double*[]` is definitely different. You really should update your post to include the *setup* and invocation of the attempted transcription of the `int` algorithm. even if it failed, it is very valuable in answers questions immediately (like is it `double[]` or `double*[]` without them drawing out.

Comment: Where one can find some explanation abou the implementation pointed out by @WhozCraig? I heard about Lomuto and Hoarse implemenation but this one seems different to my yeas.

Comment: @KcFnMi if you're asking about the link in my prior comment, it's Lomuto method. It may look a little odd because I store the pivot at the end of the sequence during the partition loop as opposed to some local temp, and the partition scheme is integrated directly into the sorting algorithm. Regardless, it is still Lomuto.

Answer (score -1):

```
void quicksort(double a[], int n) {
    if (n <= 1) return;
    double p = a[n/2];
    double b[n], c[n];
    int i, j = 0, k = 0;
    for (i=0; i < n; i++) {
        if (i == n/2) continue;
        if ( a[i] <= p) b[j++] = a[i];
        else            c[k++] = a[i];
    }
    quicksort(b,j);
    quicksort(c,k);
    for (i=0; i<j; i++) a[i] =b[i];
    a[j] = p;
    for (i= 0; i<k; i++) a[j+1+i] =c[i]; }


int main(void) {
    int i;
    /* das Array zum Sortieren */
    double test_array[] = { 5.1, 2.0, 7.8, 9.5, 6.0, 4.7, 3.6, 8.7, 1.1 };
    int N = sizeof(test_array)/sizeof(double);

    for(i = 0; i < N; i++)
        printf("%f ", test_array[i]);
    printf("\n");


    quicksort(test_array,  N);

    for(i = 0; i < N; i++)
        printf("%f ", test_array[i]);
    printf("\n");

    return 0; }
```

Works great, just changed some int to double.
If you want to learn to code in C, you better get a GOOD book. Pointers are BASIC knowledge in C/C++!!
Check this for better infos on quicksort: http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort

mfg